# Create a Timestamp table till current date in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to create a view that has all timestamps till the current date with incremental hour and save it as a view in teradata. How do I do it. I saw some ways using recursion but doesnt help.

| date_x |
| --- |
| 1/1/2021 0:00 |
| 1/1/2021 1:00 |
| 1/1/2021 2:00 |
| 1/1/2021 3:00 |
| 1/1/2021 4:00 |

```
CREATE VIEW db1.table1 WITH RECURSIVE DateRanges(CALENDAR_DATE) AS
(
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01' AS CALENDAR_DATE
FROM
( SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT NULL AS X)X) DUMMYTABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT
CALENDAR_DATE + INTERVAL '1' DAY
FROM
DateRanges
WHERE
CALENDAR_DATE < CURRENT_DATE
)
SELECT *
FROM DateRanges;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion is not very efficient for a large number of levels. But there's Teradata's hardly known NORMALIZE syntax:

```
REPLACE VIEW DateRanges AS
SELECT BEGIN(pd) AS TS
EXPAND ON PERIOD(CAST(DATE '2021-04-01' AS TIMESTAMP(0))
                ,CAST(TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)) AS TIMESTAMP(0))) AS pd
          BY INTERVAL '1' HOUR
```

Normally EXPAND ON only works when a table is accessed in FROM, but applying the TRUNC function seems to forget about this rule :-)

If the parser is still complaining about the missing from you can use any select returning a single row. I prefer sys_calendar because there's a public access right:

```
SELECT BEGIN(pd) AS TS
FROM sys_calendar.calendar
WHERE calendar_date = current_date
EXPAND ON PERIOD(CAST(DATE '2021-04-01' AS TIMESTAMP(0))
                ,CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS TIMESTAMP(0))) AS pd
          BY INTERVAL '1' HOUR
```

Comment: At least as a straight select, this isn't working for me.  Get a datetime overflow on the second cast the way it's written.  If I  use `trunc(current_timestamp)`, I get the error about needing a table in the from clause.  I can fake it with a CTE, but that doesn't work in a view :(

Comment: @dnoeth The view is getting saved and i can view the content, however I am unable to run a select statement on it. I would be needing this table to join it to other tables. How do i make this happen?

Comment: I get an error saying illegal clause or aggregation in a SELECT with no table accessed.

Comment: Then put a dummy derived table like  `FROM (SELECT 1 X) Y` before the `EXPAND`